# Is it possible to configure Sinatra .erb templates for offline using cache.manifest?

Tags: html, sinatra, offline-caching

I've looked around at various posts on the web; but it looks like it's all only for static .html files. Mephisto and rack-offline looked like they could be useful, but I couldn't figure out if they could help with sinatra templates.

My views/index.erb has 3 get do's - /part1, /part2, /part3 which hold html output; would be great if they could be cached for offline. Any pointers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll try to answer your question as best I can. I guess with "My views/index.erb has 3 get do's", you mean you have three routes in your application, `/part1`, `/part2`, and `/part3`, respectively. Those three routes are processed using ERB templates and return HTML. Now you'd like to put them into a cache manifest for offline use.

First of all: For the client, it doesn't matter if the resource behind a URL is generated dynamically or if it is a static file. You could just put `part1` (notice the missing slash) into your manifest and be done.

The effect would be that a client requests `/part1` just once, and then use the cached version until you update your manifest.

Here's the catch: If you process ERB templates, you obviously have something dynamic in the response. And that's why *I don't get why you'd want to cache the response.*

Don't get me wrong: There might be perfectly good reasons why you want to do this. And I don't see any reason why you can't put routes to dynamic resources into your cache manifest.

Comment: Thanks for a great answer. Even though dynamic as you'd assumed, I'd like to offer some content rather than a blank page as this is primarily for mobile. I suppose what I'd really like is to be able to cache, and also update if the content changes.